# Checking if an object is on the list I created

Tags: c#

I am making a code that registers a number of parameters and then checks if these parameters are already in the list, in the case, for example, I want to check if an Email is in this list, how can I do this check?

```cs
List<Professional> lprofessional = new List<Professional>();

public int role_id = 1;
public string First_name { get; set; }
public string Last_name { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public Professional(int role_id, string firstname, string lastname, string email, string phone, string description) {
    this.First_name = firstname;
    this.Last_name = lastname;
    this.Email = email;
    this.Phone = phone;
    this.Description = description;
}

public void Create()
{
    Professional pro = new Professional(role_id, First_name, Last_name, Email, Phone, Description);
    if (lprofessional.Contains(email)//Here is the check maybe...
    {
        lprofessional.Add(pro);
        role_id++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code that makes the list?

Comment: List<Professional> lprofessional = new List<Professional>(); this one?

Comment: @GSerg sadly no, since he wants a specified value, i want to the program to check if a value typed by the user is the same found in a list

Comment: What is the difference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (lprofessional.Any(p => p.Email == email))
{
    // already in the list
}
else
{
    // not yet in the list
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var p = lprofessional.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Email == email);
if (p is object)
{
    //already in the list, and you can use "p" to see or change other properties
}
else
{
    // not in the list
}
```

I know there are also newer options using **pattern matching** to do this in even less code, but I've not yet incorporated pattern matching into my own workflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
var email = "test@test.com";
var listElement = lprofessional.Where(x=> x.Email.Equals(email)).FirstOrDefault();
    if(listElement != null)
    {
    //some code
     }
```

or

```
var email = "test@test.com";
var result = lprofessional.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(email));
if( result) 
{
//some code here
}
```

Comment: What solution do you expect?